# NavLink change button color only on click moment but not setting it up

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

I have problem with Navlink button's active class my code look like this:

```
<NavLink exact to="/"><Button>Page</Button></NavLink>
```

Somehow NavLink isActive isn't working. Only when I click on button it changes class to active, but it becomes not active again after I release the button.

Button styled-component:

```
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Button = styled.button`
  width: 50%;
  height:35px;
  background: white;
  color: #71C1A1;
  padding: 0;
  border:none;

   &:active {
      background: #71C1A1;
      color: white;
    }
`;

export default Button;
```

Maybe someone could help?

Comment: active means when you click on the button, or select it with keyboard and press space or enter right? is'n't it expected behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard class given by react router to the element `<NavLink />` is `active` (you can control the given class with `activeClassName="customClass"`).

You would therefore need to style a button wrapped in a link with class `.active`. Like this:

```
const Button = styled.button`

   /* ... your other styles */

  .active & {
      background: #71c1a1;
      color: white;
  }

`;
```